# Add functional submit button

Tags: javascript, facebook, forms, iframe, mootools

I have a feeling this is easy but, I've been working on it for some hours with little success.

I'm using iframe version of LightFace modal windows:

http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-lightbox

I'm trying to find a good way to make a form submit when they press a submit button that I add to the panel.  The best I found so far is:

```
light = new LightFace.IFrame({ height:440, width:550, url: 'http://samplePage.html',
title: 'Sample' }).addButton('Submit', function() { 
window.frames[window.frames.length-1].formName.submit();},'blue')
.addButton('Close', function() {light.close(); },true).open();
```

I'm not very confident with this code but I think for the submit it gets to the iframe I'm looking for by just assuming it's the second to last one.  This works on a webpage.  Unfortunately I'm building this for a facebook app that loads within a Facebook iframe itself.  When loading in the facebook page the code doesn't do anything.

Does anyone have a better way of putting a submit button onto this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be much trouble with putting an iframe inside an iframe, however:

```
window.frames[window.frames.length-1].formName.submit();
```

...could very well cause trouble. You are kind of tracking down your form, while I would try to target the form element directly, i.e. assign it an id:

```
<form id="myForm"><!--- some form stuff --></form>
```

and use the dollar sign to get to it:

```
$('myForm').submit();
```

Comment: @kasmir This didn't work when I tried it.  As far as I can tell it works essentially the same as what I was doing so.  `$('#myForm').submit();` didn't work but `window.frames[window.frames.length-1].$('#myForm').submit();` did work (although only on it's own page not in the facebook iframe view).  I think the javascript executes on the parent page so I need to be able to drill down to the iframe before running the submit.  I can set the name of the id and have tried working with that but, I've had no luck.

Comment: Okay, well perhaps you could try a different approach, not using the 'built-in' method from Lightface. So, just adding an event listener with inline javascript in the iframe: `<script type="text/javascript"> $('myForm').addEvent('click', function(el) { el.submit(); }); </script>`. Furthermore, you could try the getBox() method from Lightface, if the problem might be related to the element not being 'seen' when using the Facebook iframe.

Comment: Got it working using the getBox() method.  That actually get's the table the iframe is in but, from there it wasn't too hard to get to the iframe.  Thanks for the help.